# JMeter RecordingController Record Request In Different Formats

Tags: java, jmeter, jmx

I have developed a webcrawler that uses Apache-JMeter.

I have created a recording controller to record request/response as `jmx` tree.

To record jmx I have two options either I integrate JMeter api in my code or use JMeter GUI, I choose both for testing. So I run the apache-jmeter from code and gui to record the request/response side-by-side. Below are the jmx results of Code-Base-JMeter and GUI-Base-JMeter for one request

**Code-Base-JMeter**

```
<HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testname="19 /rural-property-for-sale/yorkshire/north-yorkshire/holmeonspaldingmoor-26186193/" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">www.uklandandfarms.co.uk</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">0</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/rural-property-for-sale/yorkshire/north-yorkshire/holmeonspaldingmoor-26186193/</stringProp>
          <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" elementType="HeaderManager" guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
              <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="Pragma" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">Pragma</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.image_parser">true</boolProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
```

**GUI-Base-JMeter**

```
      <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="32 /" enabled="true">
        <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">www.uklandandfarms.co.uk</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding">utf-8</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.image_parser">true</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
      </HTTPSamplerProxy>
      <hashTree>
        <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
            <elementProp name="Accept-Language" elementType="Header">
              <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Language</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Header.value">en-GB,en;q=0.5</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
            <elementProp name="Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" elementType="Header">
              <stringProp name="Header.name">Upgrade-Insecure-Requests</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Header.value">1</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
            <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
              <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip, deflate</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
            <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
              <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
            <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
              <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
          </collectionProp>
        </HeaderManager>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
```

*Differences between recordings*

1) `HTTPSamplerProxy` tree ends before the *header* section in GUI-Base-JMeter recoding, while `HTTPSamplerProxy` tree ends at last of Code-Base-JMeter

2) `HeaderManager` is tag in GUI-Base-JMeter while in Code-Base-JMeter its property-value of `elementProp` tag.

3) `HeaderManager` is sibling of `HTTPSamplerProxy` in GUI-Base-JMeter while `elementProp` tag (of `HeaderManager` property-value) is child of `HTTPSamplerProxy`.

Basically whole layout is different in both recordings. I want Code-Base-JMeter recording same as GUI-Base-JMeter recoding.

I am using Apache-JMeter 3.2 (both for GUI and code)

Below is the code

**To Initialize**

```
    public void init(Integer port) throws Exception {

        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(Constants.JMETER_HOME);
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(JMeterUtils.getJMeterBinDir() + "/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
        loopController.setEnabled(true);
        loopController.setLoops(1);

        RecordingController rc = new RecordingController();
        rc.setName("Recording Controller");

        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan();

        ThreadGroup threadGroup1 = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup1.setSamplerController(loopController);
        threadGroup1.addTestElement(rc); // Target

        ListedHashTree testPlanTree = new ListedHashTree();
        testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
        testPlanTree.add(threadGroup1, testPlan);

        this.treeModel = new JMeterTreeModel(new Object());

        JMeterTreeNode root = (JMeterTreeNode) treeModel.getRoot();
        treeModel.addSubTree(testPlanTree, root);

        proxy = new ProxyControl();
        proxy.setNonGuiTreeModel(treeModel);
        proxy.setTarget(treeModel.getNodeOf(threadGroup1));
        proxy.setGroupingMode(2); // GROUPING_IN_SIMPLE_CONTROLLERS = 2
//      proxy.setGroupingMode(3); // GROUPING_STORE_FIRST_ONLY = 3
        proxy.setSamplerTypeName("2"); // SAMPLER_TYPE_HTTP_SAMPLER_HC4 = "2"
        proxy.setRegexMatch(Boolean.TRUE);
        proxy.setPort(port); // Global Settings -> Port
        proxy.setCaptureHttpHeaders(Boolean.TRUE);
        proxy.setSamplerFollowRedirects(Boolean.TRUE);
//      proxy.setSamplerRedirectAutomatically(Boolean.TRUE);
        proxy.setSamplerDownloadImages(Boolean.TRUE);

        treeModel.addComponent(proxy, (JMeterTreeNode) root.getChildAt(1));
    }
```

**Start JMeter**

```
this.proxy.startProxy();
```

**Stop/Record JMeter**

```
/**
 * The method stop() is use to stop JMeter recording controller proxy.
 * 
 * @return The tree that is recorded till now
 */
public String stop() {

    OutputStream out = null;

    try {
        this.proxy.stopProxy();

        if (this.treeModel == null) {
            return null;
        }

        out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        HashTree tree = treeModel.getTestPlan();

        JMeter.convertSubTree(tree);

        SaveService.saveTree(tree, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

    return out.toString();
}
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: @user7294900 I want Code-Base-JMeter recording same as GUI-Base-JMeter recoding.

Answer (score 0):

*Warning*: This is not a legitimate solution/answer, its just a workaround as nobody give me any solution yet.

I make an xslt expression to transform Code-Base-JMeter-Jmx to Gui-Base-JMeter-Jmx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <hashTree>
            <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
                <xsl:copy-of select="HTTPSamplerProxy/elementProp[@elementType = 'HeaderManager']/collectionProp[@name='HeaderManager.headers']" />
            </HeaderManager>
            <hashTree />
        </hashTree>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="HTTPSamplerProxy/elementProp[@elementType = 'HeaderManager']" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now what if in next version(s) of JMeter they change the jmx/xml output, then again I have to change my xslt to cater the change, which is not a good way at all.

So I am still hungry to have a legitimate solution.